# How to save dto data as json in oracle and read it back using java/hibernate

Tags: java, jquery, json, oracle, blob

I am trying to save data into an oracle(12c) database as a json (blob) object using java and hibernate. i am new to this concept of saving data as json and reading it back. below is my table that i have create in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE blob_table_example
(
  id number,
  jsonId NUMBER NOT NULL,
  month_date DATE NOT NULL,
  jsonData blob NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE blob_table_example
ADD CONSTRAINT jsonData_json CHECK (jsonData IS JSON  FORMAT JSON STRICT);
```

And inserted data into the table using below query:

```
insert into blob_table_example 
values ( 1,1,'01-Jan-20', utl_raw.cast_to_raw ( '{
"department": "Month data",
"data": [
{
  "name": "string1",
  "monthsData": [11,12,13,14,15]
},
{
  "name": "string2",
  "monthsData": [110,210,310,410,150]
}
]
}' ));
```

i tried to update the existing blob object as below:

```
update blob_table_example set jsonData = utl_raw.cast_to_raw('{
"department": "Monthsdata",
"data": [
{
  "name": "string1",
  "monthsData": [11,12,13,14,15]
},
{
  "name": "string23",
  "monthsData": [110,210,310,410,150]
}
]
}') where id = 1;
```

i am able to insert and update the json blob object in oracle but I need a solution to read this json object using java/hibernate which can be used in jquery for further operations. can anyone help me with the solution of reading the json blob object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of saving the json string you could create a table that has the json attributes as columns. Or is there something against it ?

Comment: Actually i have lot of data and too many columns need to be added if i save in a tabular fashion. so i am saving as json object

Comment: ok, then i would use a clob and not blob , then you can keep the json in a string and not in a byte array. have a look here: https://thorben-janssen.com/mapping-blobs-and-clobs-with-hibernate-and-jpa/
You could then give your entity object methods to manipulate the string, using a json parser that would parse the string in  e.g. a Map with the json content.

Comment: Thank you for the above solution. I am new to this concept, so can i save the entire json as string using clob and also what would be the structure of oracle table. can you please clarify. thanks in advance.

Comment: the easiest solution is probably to let hibernate generate the table from the entities automatically. 
This can be done with the property <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>.
for more options look here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution that solved half of my problem i am able to save the json in the clob column.can you help me in converting this jclob(clob is having json data) object to pure json object or string in java. thanks in advacne